# JSONB: Finding an element with a null attribute in array of objects

Tags: postgresql, json, psql

With the following table in psql 10:

```
CREATE TABLE logs(id serial, data JSONB); 
INSERT INTO logs VALUES
  (1, '[{"name":"test1","date":"2018-01-09"},{"name":"test2","date":"2018-01-10"}]'),
  (2, '[{"name":"test3","date":"2018-01-10"},{"name":"test4","date":null}]');
```

How do I find row #2 by querying the date=null value in the array?

I already know how to query by name to find row#2:

```
AND data @> '[{"name": "test4"}]'
```

But I don't know how you can query for rows with or without a null date attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this,

```
SELECT * FROM logs WHERE data @> '[{"date":null}]';
 id |                                    data                                    
----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  2 | [{"date": "2018-01-10", "name": "test3"}, {"date": null, "name": "test4"}]
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks Evan, but how does one do the inverse. Select where date is not null?

Comment: For example, retrieving name=test2 where its date is not null.

Comment: @jprado that's not going to work well: that's not what JSON was designed for. For something easy though you could do `SELECT * FROM logs WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM logs WHERE data @> '[{"date":null}]'`